# How do I change hashing algorithm?

Tags: 8

We are migrating a site to Drupal 8. The passwords are hashed with MD5, but Drupal 8 uses a different hashing algorithm.

Which file should I edit to change the hashing system to MD5?

We are aware of the risk, but it has been decided.

Comment: Consider the following approachs to upgrading your hashing system: [How to upgrade the hashing method of a live database without compromising security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17268/how-to-upgrade-the-hashing-method-of-a-live-database-without-compromising-securi)

Comment: The reason to replace the hash algorithm is bad, but the question itself is valid and should not voted down. Especially since Drupal does support password rehasing which allow transparent migration of unsecure hashes.

Comment: As a general rule you should never edit Drupal core (or contrib) code to change its behavior. Drupal is extremely flexible and provide extension points for virtually all its behavior. It is usually done though alter hooks, and in Drupal 8, be replacing services with custom one.

Comment: Perhaps it is not clear how insecure MD5 of SHA1 is. On my laptop I can MD5 or SHA1 over 1,000,000 passwords per second. My ~90% attack: 1. Sort the hashes. 2. Get a 10M password list. 3. For each password run SHA1. 4. Compare each hash to the sorted list of hashes with a binary search, (~17 compares). 5. For each match find the matching record(s). Using my desktop I can perform SHA1 in ~ 1 us.. Time: ~1 us * 10M (passwords) = less than 10 seconds. Nice.

Comment: Drupal 8 uses sha512 (from the SHA-2 set of hash functions), not SHA1. Drupal uses salt and repeated hashing for passwords (minimum 8 repetitions), see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword%3A%3Ahash/8.1.x for details.

Answer (score 6):

In Drupal 8.1+, password hashing and checking is managed by a service that can be replaced in your site's `services.yml` file.  You need to provide your own implementation of [`PasswordInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PasswordInterface.php/interface/PasswordInterface/8.1.x).

Instead of replacing the hash method, it would be safer for your implementation to inherit from [`PhpassHashedPassword`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/class/PhpassHashedPassword/8.1.x) and override the `check()` method to accept your MD5 hashes (but otherwise use the parent implementation). You can use a dedicated prefix to detect old hashes. And thanks to the [`PhpassHashedPassword::needsRehash($hash)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword%3A%3AneedsRehash/8.1.x), your password will be securely rehashed over time.

For instance, the following code expect you old hashes to be prefixed with `BAD$` in the database.

```
class MyPasswordService extends PhpassHashedPassword {
  function check ($password, $hash) {
    if (substr($hash, 0, 4) == 'BAD$') {
      // Migrate MD5 has
      $stored_hash = substr($hash, 4);
      $computed_hash = ... old and insecure hash code ...;
      return $computed_hash && Crypt::hashEquals($stored_hash, $computed_hash);
    }
    return parent::check($password, $hash);
  }
}
```

Comment: SHA1 is essentially no more secure than MD5 for passwords, on my computer there is no real difference in speed, both are over 2,000,000 hashes/sec. So much for "old and insecure hash code". It is really better to replace MD5 with functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and etc.

Comment: Drupal 8 uses sha512 (from the SHA-2 set of hash functions), not SHA1.

Comment: Drupal uses salt and repeated hashing for passwords (minimum 8 repetitions), see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword%3A%3Ahash/8.1.x for details.